# Format a number with optional decimal places in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I have numbers in cells in Excel. I want the numbers formatted so that if they have decimal places they show to a maximum of two, and if they have no decimal places it doesn't show any.

For example.

- 15 should be formatted as 15, **NOT 15.00**
- 14.3453453 should be formatted as 14.35
- 12.1 should be formatted as 12.1
- 0 should be formatted as 0

The closest custom format code I've come up with is `0.##`. Unfortunately this formats `15.00` as **15.** (note the extra decimal point).

To further complicate the issue, the spreadsheet is a result of an export from SQL Server Reporting Services. So no macros are possible. Oh well, it looks like `0.##` is my best bet, and they can just live with the extra period.

Answer (score 47):

Alternatively, you can solve the "optional" decimal point problem using the following solution:

Number Format: `General;[Red](General)`

This will add the decimal place and fractional value accordingly, while formatting negative numbers in a more legible way.

As for the poster's original question, you still need to round/truncate the "extra" decimal points using a formula. However, this is a simple formula of `=ROUND(<value>,<desired decimal places>)` that is not extremely computationally expensive.

Examples:

```
2500 -> 2500
0.25 -> 0.25
-2500 -> (2500)
-0.25 -> (0.25)
```

Comment: This answer deserves more upvotes. It handled the decimal point correctly without using conditional formatting. In my specific case, I want to show all decimal places, so I don't even need to modify the formula.

Comment: `General` has the problem of going into scientific notation if the number has too many decimals, e.g. `2.6532E-06` instead of `0.0000026532`.

Comment: +1 This was helpful for me in solving a specific problem of needing to display values of thousands of dollars (e.g. show $40,000 as $40k, and $10,500 as $10.5k), in the labels of a Pivot Table (where conditional formatting is not an option). Format code `$General\k` did it perfectly!

Comment: Also applies to Gnumeric: just use Format: General instead of Format: Number

Comment: what is that numberformat? "General;[Red](General)" what is that? Where to apply it? In Excel it does not work!

Comment: Any idea how to add thousand separators to  ````General;[Red](General)````?

Comment: @MsGISRocker, you ever figure that one out? I'm looking myself.

Comment: A problem with this solution is that you are losing the precision you are rounding off.

Answer (score 25):

Excel custom formats can provide a partial answer

Custom formats for numbers in Excel are entered in this format:

```
positive number format;negative number format;zero format;text format
```

One format that comes close to your requirement, but leaves in the decimal place for numbers with no decimals is:

```
#,###.??;(#,###.??);0
```

Example:

- 15 is displayed as `15.`
- 14.3453453 is displayed as `14.35`
- 12.1 is displayed as `12.1`
- 0.5 is displayed as `.5`
- 0 is displayed as `0`

Comment: This is by far the best answer.

Comment: Yet doesn't actually provide a valid solution, or even a possible work around. It does have useful information regarding custom number formats.

Comment: 15 is displayed as ,15.

Comment: who needs to display `15.`? that is for sure an Excel bug!

Answer (score 24):

Apply Conditional Formatting for non-decimal numbers.

For example, A1 is the target cell.

1. Format A1 as "###,###.00". This will be used for decimal number.
2. Define Conditional Formatting for non-decimal numbers.

   - Condition: Cell Value equal to =TRUNC(A1).
   - Format: `###,###`

Below is the result:

```
12       =>  12
14.231   => 14.23
15.00000 => 15
17.3     => 17.30
```

Comment: Just had an issue with number 4.001, which rounded to 4.00 on display, yet would not satisfy the conditional formatting formula (4.001 <> 4) and would still show as "4.". I used this conditional formula to solve it: =ROUND($A1;2)=TRUNC($A1)

Comment: @leokhorn alternatively `=ABS(A1-TRUNC(A1))<0.00499999999999989` I would have used `<0.005` but my Excel was having internal rounding issues such that `abs(4.005-trunc(4.005))<>0.005`

Answer (score 16):

My Answer removes the decimal point **AND** Removes 0 value

in conditional formatting write:

```
General;#;;@
```

This should do the trick.

Comment: This displays zeroes as empty cells.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. Thank you.

Comment: I used `General°;#°;;@°` to show degrees, like 5°, 3.5°, 2.25°, etc... without all the annoying trailing 0's which imply a level of precision that is not present in the original measurement. Thanks for the tip!

Comment: This is a very bad solution. The syntax, without condition blocks, is `POSITIVE;NEGATIVE;ZERO;TEXT`.

@Mr.J your code is saying “Use the ‘General’ format for positive numbers; Round negative numbers to the nearest integer, then remove the negative symbol; Display nothing if zero; Display text, if text.”

The `General` format automatically removes decimal points and zeros, so your code does nothing useful at all, other than breaking expectations. Not even the 2 decimal limit, either.

@user207863 the code you're looking for is `General°`, which will add the degree symbol to any number.

Answer (score 9):

I ran into this recently in Excel 2007 and just ended up using the 'TRUNC' function in the value cells:

```
  value  =TRUNC(B5,1)
      0      0
      5      5
    5.4    5.4
  65.43   65.4
765.432  765.4
```

Worked exactly the way I wanted it to...

Comment: Yes, both TRUNC(x,2) and ROUND(x,2) will do the job (depending on what kind of rounding method you're after).  You then just need to set the cell formatting to "General" and the decimal places will only be displayed if needed.

(I vote to mark Droj's post as the answer.)

Comment: This solution drops precision in case the number is used in further calculations.

Answer (score 7):

Here's one method using conditional formatting.

1. Right click your cell, choose "Format Cell"
2. Select "Custom"
3. Enter "0.####" (add more or fewer #s to control the maximum number of decimal places)
4. Click OK
5. With the cell still selected, use "Conditional Formatting" (may be a menu item in Format or button in Home depending on your Excel version)
6. Add a new rule, based on the formula "=MOD(H32,1)=0"

   **edit** - better formula is "=MOD(ROUND(H32,2),1)=0"  with the '2' being the desired number of decimal places.  previous formula leave trailing decimal point if the number rounds to an integer.

   *Replace H32 in the formula with the ID of your cell, but MAKE SURE THERE ARE NO $ SIGNS! (No $ signs ensures that you to copy the format to other cells)*
7. For the format of this rule, select the number tab, choose "Custom"
8. This time, enter the formula "0"
9. Click OK enough times to return to the sheet (varies among excel versions)

There you go, enjoy responsibly!  If you want to copy the format to other cells, remember that you can copy the cell and use "Paste Special" with the "Format" option.

Comment: Could you clarify if this only applies to certain (or more recent versions) of Excel? I am still using 2003 (and I suspect an embarrassing number of others are as well) and when I go to Conditional formatting, I have no option to modify the number formatting, only Font, Border, and Patterns. Thanks

Comment: I just tried this approach on Excel 2010 and it worked fine. It will not work with earlier versions of Excel (at least that's what my "compatibility mode" checker in Excel 2010 tells me).

Answer (score 2):

Remember that in Reporting Services, you can write an expression for the number formatting, too. In my situation, I used

```
iif(floor(Fields!numericFieldName.Value)=Fields!numericFieldName.Value,"0","0.##")
```

as the number format expression.
This produced an Excel file with two cell formats, selected by whether or not the value was an integer.

Answer (score 1):

Are you / your users inputting values directly in the cells, or are they being populated by a formula or a macro?

If the cells are not being populated directly by a human, you *could* store the calculated values in a hidden range and then display formatted text to the user with a formula like this:

```
=IF(ROUND(A1,2)=INT(A1),TEXT(A1,"0"),TEXT(A1,"0.0#"))
```

(where 'A1' is the cell being referenced)

The formula will display values like this:

```
 -------------------------
 |Original     |Formatted|
 |-------------+---------|
 |         15  |       15|
 | 14.3453453  |    14.35|
 |       12.1  |     12.1|
 |          0  |        0|
 |    -15.123  |   -15.12|
 |      1.004  |        1|
 -------------------------
```

NB: The formula output is a text string, not a numeric, so:

- The output defaults to being left-aligned.
- You cannot use the output in any further calculations (instead, you should use the original cell being referenced)

Answer (score 1):

Format cell as 'General' then under data validation restrict values to decimals

Comment: If you need to avoid adding formulas (and probably a new column) to your spreadsheet then Fred's suggestion may be the best.

Comment: This will not allow people to enter numbers with more than the visual limit of decimal digits.

Answer (score 1):

This doesn't have to be quite so complicated - it can be done exclusively with Conditional Formatting.  I have Excel 2010, so this may not work for earlier versions.

1. Format the cells to be General.  The number of decimal places for some numbers may be very high.
2. Highlight a cell and click Conditional Formatting.  Click New Rule, then "Use a Formula".
3. Use the formula =(B1-INT(B1))>0 (where B1 is the cell you're formatting)
4. Click the Format button and choose Custom.  Enter [=0]0;.## into the Type field.
5. Hit Enter several times.
6. Click on Conditional Formatting again, click Manage Rules, and Edit the rule you just created.  Change the range in the "Applies to" field to cover the range you want covered.

All done.

Answer (score 0):

Further to Luke's great answer above here is a variation based on his work. I didn't want to have a zero in the cell if there was no value. Leave your cell format as general and used this formula:

```
=IF((A1=""), "",IF(ROUND(A1,2)=INT(A1),TEXT(A1,"0"),TEXT(A1,"0.0#")))
```

Again where A1 is the cell being referenced.

Answer (score 0):

Using the `Round` function to provide significant figures. This does not change the number of 
decimal places displayed however. Just format the cell with `general` number format though.

```
ROUND(MyValue,Sig.figs - 1 - INT(LOG10(ABS(MyValue)))
```

Comment: Why all the complicated INT(LOG... formula?  Why not just ROUND(value,2) and format as General?

Comment: @SimonEast `Round(value, 2)` fixes at 0.00, where as 2 sig figs of 0.0125 would be 0.013 and not 0.01

Answer (score 0):

```
B1=IF(ROUND(A1,2)=INT(A1),TEXT(A1,"0"),TEXT(A1,"0.##"))
C1=IF(ROUND(B1,2)=INT(B1),TEXT(B1,"0"),TEXT(B1,"0.##"))
```

No more orphan decimal points.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be the simplest way to have a Decimal shown when there are fractional numbers - and No Decimal shown for whole numbers:

```
=TEXT(ROUND(Base_Number,Max_Decimal_Places),"general")
```

or with cell references:

```
=TEXT(ROUND(A1,2),"general")
```

Gives

> 15 = 15
>      9.23432234 = 9.23

Comment: Welcome to SuperUser @lookingforsame. Just a note to watch out for the hidden details of questions though. In this case, the op is saying the output is from SQL, if macro's are not possible, formulae may not be either. It's sometimes worth putting in a question as a comment before answering. Good to see a new person though, happy answering!