# Excel - Conditional Formatting: Why can't I format decimal rounding? Only Font, Border, Fill?

Tags: microsoft-excel, mac, worksheet-function, conditional-formatting, microsoft-excel-2016

[In another post that is asking the same question that I ultimately have](https://superuser.com/questions/205759/format-a-number-with-optional-decimal-places-in-excel), the top answer says to conditionally format the cells using the formula ###,###.  But when I go into conditional formatting, my only options are changing the Font, Border, and Fill of the text...nothing to do with the actual numbers.  Help?  Microsoft Excel 2016 Mac

[image: Screenshot showing my only options: Font, Border, Fill]

Comment: You've skipped a step. You need to format the cell with `###.##`, then apply a conditional format on the cell afterwards.

Comment: Hey Michael, I've done a direct formatting of the cells to show 2 decimal places, like the first step says.  Now, I want to conditionally format those cells to show only the whole number (without the decimals) when it is ###.00.  The answer says to do that with conditional formatting, but I only get the option to basically 'color' the cells, not change decimal formatting.  Any idea what I'm missing?

Comment: Was about to write an answer when I see the tag `mac` and his screenshot

Comment: I'm not an expert in Mac Office, but what the *Style* does?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per your screen shot and [other web examples](https://www.techonthenet.com/excel/questions/cond_format1_2011.php), it appears that Excel 2016 for Mac can only format Font, Border and Fill.

From [answers.microsoft.com](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/msoffice_excel-mso_mac/excel-2016-for-mac-number-format-conditional/6a5ba938-dba9-41b0-a3f6-a980200d938f):

> Excel for Mac does not have the interface for number formatting in the Conditional Format dialog. The Mac version does respond correctly to Conditional Formatting generated in Excel for Windows.

Why? We can only guess as to Microsoft's thinking. It seems like a large omission.

Comment: When I click "new rule" under conditional formatting, this is all I see.  I don't see your "New Formatting Rule" dialog box with the "Format..." button.